# Views Date expose filter end date excluding the given date

Tags: datetime, views

I have created a view of commerce orders, listing all orders, as expose filter I have added two date filters on field "When Order is Created" with one I am giving operator as "is greater or equal to"(start date) and with other as "is less than or equal to"(end date). As output I am getting all orders after or on Start Date filter but with End date filter I am seeing results filtered by End Date - 1 (not including the given date). How I can make the end date filter to be included in the filter results?
Thanks in advance.